# Why is this returning undefined? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line `<table id='<?= $value['Name']?>'>` in my PHP which just sets an ID which I can target.

This table is inside a `<div>` with `id="god"`.

But when i click the table which has this script:

```
$("#god table").click(function(){
    var link = $(this).id;
    alert(link);
});
```

It alerts `undefined` - could you tell me why that is?

My best guess would be that it targets the `<td>` which I click on for the `$(this)` but I am not sure - and I do not know how to test that.

Comment: use the `attr()` method, you're mixing javascript and jquery on the same line

Comment: Maybe just a typo here, but you say the div has the id `God` but your selector is for `#god`. Case matters.

Comment: that was a typo :) it is lowercase ^^ but thumbs up for noticing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following:

```
var link = this.id;
```

The jQuery object `$(this)` does not have a propery `id`.

Note: **DO NOT** use `$(this).attr('id')` when you can use `this.id` which is way more efficient. also, note that `id` is case sensitive so be consistent with "God" and "god".

Comment: @JesperJacobsen consider accepting the best answer which helped you solving your problem by clicking on the "accept" tick. :)

Comment: Nice work man people should know dom and javascript before relying on jquery too much.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var link =  $(this).id;
```

Supposed to be

either

```
   var link =  $(this).attr('id');
```

**or**

```
   var link =  this.id;
```

`$(this)` is a jQuery object. And it does not have the `.id` property